# Отладочная панель yii2

Tags: yii2

Всем привет. Поставил basic yii на хостинг. Все работает, но вот заметил что у других внизу есть отладочная панель, а у меня ее нету? как ее включить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По идее в `/config/web.php` внизу должно быть написано:

```
if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ];
}

return $config;
```

а в `/web/index.php` есть строчки

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
```

которые определяют, соответственно, константы и то, будет ли отображена панель.

---

Но на продакшне включать дебаг панель - не надо.

---

Если надо показывать панель для определенных лиц, кто с других компов заходит на сайт, тогда нужно прописывать allowedIPs

например в конфиге:

```
'modules' => [
    'debug' => [
        'class' => yii\debug\Module',
        'allowedIPs' => ['222.13.54.123', '666.122.4.15']
    ]
]
```

либо в секции `if (YII_ENV_DEV) { .... }`  дописать

```
 $config['modules']['debug']['allowedIPs'] = ['222.13.54.123', '666.122.4.15'];
```

или так:

```
if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' =>'yii\debug\Module',
        'allowedIPs' => ['222.13.54.123', '666.122.4.15']
    ];

   ...
```

Comment: Странно и то и то написано но панели нету, хотя все тестирую на удаленном хостинге. Не на локалке может в этом дело?

Comment: Надо сюда добавить $config['modules']['debug']['allowedIPs'] = ['192.168.22.45', '192.168.22.46', '192.168.1.12'];

Comment: @duddeniska ааа. так вы имели в виду показывать панель для тех определенных лиц, кто  с других компов заходит на сайт? ну тогда да, нужно allowedIPs прописывать...... добавил в ответ....ответ на вопрос, которого в итоге не было :D